# With php cURL get filename from file header

Tags: php, file, curl, filenames, http-headers

I have this php cURL function:

```
function curl_login($url,$data,$proxy,$proxystatus){
$fp = fopen("cookietlt.txt", "w");
fclose($fp);
$login = curl_init();
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
if ($proxystatus == 'on') {
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
}
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
ob_start();      // prevent any output
return curl_exec ($login); // execute the curl command
ob_end_clean();  // stop preventing output

curl_close ($login);

unset($login);    
}                  
function curl_grab_page($site,$proxy,$proxystatus){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
if ($proxystatus == 'on') {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
ob_start();      // prevent any output
return curl_exec ($ch); // execute the curl command
ob_end_clean();  // stop preventing output
curl_close ($ch);
}


curl_login('http://www.site.tdl/login.php','username=test&password=demo','','off');
curl_grab_page('http://www.site.tdl/1965.torrent','','off');
```

I need to get filename from file(*http://www.site.tdl/1965.torrent*) header into variable.

*http://www.site.tdl/1965.torrent* header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Linux.Mint.torrent"
Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent
Content-Length: 4525
```

So output will be Linux.Mint. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I know this question is kind of old, but I'd like to clarify `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` a bit, I found the documentation on php.net to be confusing.

curl will send the header callback function one header at a time. The call back function must return the number of bytes read or else curl will fail (and the request will end)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "readHeader");

function readHeader($ch, $header)
{
     // read headers
    echo "Read header: ", $header;
    return strlen($header);
}
```

Example output:

```
 Read header: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Read header: Server: nginx/0.8.32
    Read header: Date: Wed, 31 Mar 2010 14:23:18 GMT
    Read header: Content-Type: image/jpeg
    Read header: Content-Length: 886308
    Read header: Connection: close
    Read header: Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Read header:
```

Without the return from readHeader, curl will end after the first header is sent.

Comment: Just snagged this for something I'm working on, shouldn't the curl_setopt have readHeader in quotes?

Comment: True. Thanks joshtronic. I just copied and appended from the answer below mine

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a callback to read the headers.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, readHeader);

function readHeader($ch, $header)
{
     // read headers
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the other answers, your call to `readheader` will fail unless you return `strlen( $header )`.